# What does it mean when a person is 'besieged by apoplexy'?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when a person is 'besieged by apoplexy'?

Not sure what this means either.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned where you found this phrase. Apoplexy has a weakened modern meaning that just means _very angry - to the point of speechlessness_ (speechlessness from part of the older meaning of having had a stroke but more generally just internal bleeding)

Answer (score 2):

I would understand it to mean "overcome with anger". - **Furious**

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange/inappropriate expression, as "apoplexy," with both its meanings

a *dated* :  stroke

b :  gross hemorrhage into a cavity or into the substance of an organ

is quite a short process, while "besieged" shows a prolonged condition.

No surprisingly, there are no hits on it at Google Books.

["besieged by apoplexy"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%27besieged%20by%20apoplexy%27&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=KvwWVfbQM4PHsQS_z4DgBQ#tbm=bks&q=%22besieged%20by%20apoplexy%22)

About 0 results

Instead, these are idiomatic:

["struck by apoplexy"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%27besieged%20by%20apoplexy%27&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=KvwWVfbQM4PHsQS_z4DgBQ#tbm=bks&q=%22struck%20by%20apoplexy%22%20About%2020,500%20results)

About 20,500 results

["stricken by apoplexy"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%27besieged%20by%20apoplexy%27&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=KvwWVfbQM4PHsQS_z4DgBQ#tbm=bks&q=%22stricken%20by%20apoplexy%22)

both using verbs showing a fast action.

About 8,030 results

Comment: _besieged_ could be repeated ministrokes (TIE) or even Apoplexy cutaneous which I think would cover Dengue Fever (and that's not a quick way to go).

Comment: Interesting, of course, and possible.

Comment: I suspect the original quote is modern and involves _angry_ but until WhipPoorWill whistles in with a proper citation we'll never know.